# Get distinct items from DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have data being returned in a DataTable that looks like:

> Department | EmployeeName
>
> 1 | Employee1
>
> 1 | Employee1
>
> 2 | Employee2
>
> 3 | Employee3
>
> 3 | Employee3
>
> 3 | Employee3

I'm trying to get only distinct rows and put it into a collection, like so:

```
IEnumerable<Department> departments = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
    new Department
        {
            DepartmentID = Int32.Parse(row["DepartmentID"].ToString()),
            Employee = new Employee { EmployeeName = row["EmployeeName"].ToString() }
        }).Distinct();
```

It should only return 3 rows, but instead it's returning all 6.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but one of the following may work for you ..........

just do this

```
var distrows= table1.AsEnumerable().Distinct();
```

will do your task..........than create collection of department form the `distrow`..

```
IEnumerable<Department> departments = (from DataRow dRow in distrows   
                         new Department
        {
            DepartmentID = Int32.Parse(row["DepartmentID"].ToString()),
            Employee = new Employee { EmployeeName = row["EmployeeName"].ToString() }
        });
```

**OR**

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows
            select new {col1=dRow["dataColumn1"],col2=dRow["dataColumn2"]}).Distinct();


IEnumerable<Department> departments = (from DataRow dRow in distrows   
                             new Department
            {
                DepartmentID = Int32.Parse(distinctRows.col1),
                Employee = new Employee { EmployeeName = distinctRows.col2.ToString() }
            });
```

Comment: That will return an IEnumerable collection of AnonymousType, I need it to be returned as IEnumerable<Department>

Comment: @Steven  - as i written you can use that anonymous type result to create your dept collection

Answer (score 0):

**Class/Schema**

```
public class abc
{
    public int id;
}
```

---

**DataTable and Records**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("id", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["id"] = 1;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

---

**Query**

```
var qa = dt.AsEnumerable()
.Select(row => new
{
    Id = row.Field<int>("id"),
})
.Distinct();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

what i think the problem here is that you are creating different objects with have no implementation for comparing the equality based on some propertiese. so the `Distinct()` method compares the refference of the objects and hence concludes that all the objects are different because they point to different reffrences.

what you shoud do instead is try parsing the information in an object that implements `IEqualityComparer` and then use `.Select(<IEqualityComparer>).Distinct()`