# how to get the whole records from the datatable by selecting distinct values in a specified column

Tags: vb.net

i have a datatable with 20 records one column contains the duplicate values. i need to select distinct values from the column with whole records.Please help me.
thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you selecting the records? Please post some code so we can see the context you are working in.

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain yourself more?

You can use LINQ with your datatable like this:

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in dTable.Rows
        select new {col1=dRow["dataColumn1"]}).Distinct();
```

Refer to this question for further help: [Get distinct items from DataTable using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299223/get-distinct-items-from-datatable-using-linq)

You should google this better before asking.

Hope it helps.